# What type of English accent is this?

Tags: accent, received-pronunciation

I came across these adverts: [EPO 2013](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-vudJyVZ10&ab_channel=dailynews326)  [EPO 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4D6SjO702Mk&feature=youtu.be) on TV a few years back and was curious as to what type of accent the speaker has. I've been told by a linguistic professor who is English  that it is a 'posh' English accent but definitely would not be considered RP (Received Pronunciation), which is the standard accent used by broadcasters on the radio and on television.

The reason I ask is that I'm am a native English speaker who's accent and pronunciation have been 'muddled' by having moved through 4 different countries during my childhood. I'd like to improve my accent for personal and professional reasons perhaps entering the film or voiceover industry. I have a slight English/Irish accent but the pronunciations make some words difficult to understand and hopefully emulating a voiceover artist would help.

Comment: Depends what the professor means by 'posh'! The speaker's accent is 'educated' but not 'upper-class', which is how I would understand 'posh'.

Comment: It seems to me that someone in the BrE world ought to be able to suggest a source for listening to the kind of English the OP is looking for.

Comment: I wouldn't class that as either a 'posh' or particularly an 'educated' accent. It's a fairly generic, middle class, Southern English accent (with a prosody common to commercial radio presenters, advertising voiceovers, etc.), with no obvious 'local' markers (e.g,it's not detectably London, or West Midlands, or West Country) ... maybe somebody can give a more exact description?

Comment: ... on second listen, I might guess East English Midlands ... but somebody from that region can no doubt be much more precise?

Comment: The speaker on those videos does not have a 'posh' accent. The accent is that of an educated working class man from the north-west of the UK (his vowels suggest that he may originally be from somewhere in the Liverpool/Manchester/Lancashire area, as does the slightly emphatic 'g' pronunciation at the end of 'unsung').

Comment: Actually, it sounds a lot like fake accents that are occasionally heard here in the US.  But it could be European, in addition to the various British origins suggested.  It's pretty generic.

Comment: @KateBunting In the UK, isn't a 'posh' accent the same as RP? And isn't the 'educated' accent either RP or close to it?

Comment: @Kiloran_speaking sorry but  I'm a bit confused by 'working class'. I've always heard the term used for people who are below middle class. Was that your intention or is that synonymous with middle class?

Comment: @HotLicks do you mean the accent is fake in a derogatory way or rather someone trying to be 'posh'? I know here in Ireland, there's a 'D4' accent (range between moderate Dublin and Generic London accent) which is generally despised for its obnoxiousness to people.

Comment: @myopicflight - I mean "fake" in the sense of being intended to create a certain impression in an advertisement or some such.  You wouldn't have someone with an AAVE accent do the voiceover in an ad for a cruise of the  Rhine -- you'd likely pick someone with a vague French/German accent.  And many voice actors can do several different accents, quite convincingly.

Comment: @myopicflight: I was using 'working class' a little sloppily I think - as a shorthand for 'not upper class (ie posh), and not someone who went to a public school - ie someone who came from a specific part of the country and who had regional accent before choosing to drop that accent and acquire a more neutral one'. Yes, generally working class means people who are below the middle class. In this particular instance, I can't say for sure whether the speaker is middle class or working class, though something tells me it's the latter. Either way, his accent is fairly neutral now.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Kiloran_speaking. That description is spot on.

It's not a posh accent.

And RP is by no means the standard for media broadcasts these days. These days, clear pronunciation (with or without a regional accent) is what counts.

Actually, having the right regional accent may increase your chances of getting a job in the media. Research into accent and prestige a few years back suggested that Irish and Scottish accents are high prestige, whereas Birmingham and Liverpool accents have least prestige. See: https://volcanocity.com/blog/10-best-and-worst-british-accents/